# Markov chain: Stationary distribution

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I hope my question qualifies for the Stackexchange forum and please bear with me for being new to this field of probability theory. I understand the concept of a stationary distribution of a Markov chain, i.e. given a Markov chain with transitioning matrix $P$, there is a distribution $\pi$ satisfying

$$ \pi P = \pi. $$
In other words, $\pi$ is a left eigenvector of $P$ with eigenvalue $1.$

However, my concern is that such a distribution $\pi$ is only relevant if it can actually be reached, meaning: The Markov chain has got a state space $S:= \{ s_1, s_2, \ldots \}$ and we need to pick one of them to start. Consequently, our initial distribution must be of the form $x_0 := (0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Either $\pi$ is one of these distributions, or, it can be reached after $n$ steps from there, i.e. there is an $n \in \mathbb N$ with
$$\pi = x_0 P^n.$$
But what if we cannot find such $n$? Then the Markov chain has got a stationary distribution but it cannot be reached! Does the definition of a stationary distribution make any sense if we do not require that property to be satisfied as well?

Best regards!

Comment: Where is the problem ? Either you have it as a limit, in general indeed never reached, or you begin with it and you stay with it...

Comment: I wouldn't call it a problem but to me, it doesn't make sense to think about a distribution that can never be reached. It appears to be (practically) irrelevant. But perhaps my way of thinking is just wrong! :-) Or let me rephrase: Why textbooks do not mention this possible aspect.

Comment: Typically it is approached as a limit rather than reached.

Comment: Ah, I see! OK, that makes a lot of sense!